# How to reveal a specific letter in a string for Python?

Tags: python, pygame

I am in high school and am currently teaching myself Python. I am programming Hangman and it is going well so far (it is not very organized yet) but I am having a problem. I created a list of words that I would use for the game and replaced them with asterisks using the range function. Here is the code for that:

```py
words = ['utopia', 'prosecute', 'delirious', 'superficial', 'fowl', 'abhorrent', 'divergent', 
         'noxious', 'scarce','lavish', 'hinder', 'onerous', 'colossal', 'infringe']

picked_words = random.choice(words)

for i in range(len(picked_words)):
    print(picked_words.replace(picked_words,'*'), end = '')
```

I am at the point where I am guessing the letters and I need to slowly reveal the position of certain letters. I have tried looking for certain functions (I even thought that the find() function would work since it prints the location of a letter in a string but it did not) and I am at a loss. Especially for words with multiples of the same letter such as "onerous" and "infringe." I will write the code that I have so far for this section:

```py
def right_letter(correct):
   if correct == True:
       print("There are {} {}'s.".format(number_of_char, guess))
       for x in range(len(picked_words)):
           print(picked_words.replace(picked_words,guess, #find way to fill in specific letters),end = '')
```

I have no clue what parts of the code are necessary to get an answer but my code is really unorganized because I do not know proper techniques yet.  The portion that says **for x in range(len(picked_words))...** is where I am having trouble. The rest of the code ran fine before I added the print statement underneath it. Basically I am asking how to change a certain character or specific characters and put them where they belong. For example, if the randomized word was "infringe" and the first guess was "i" how do I go from ******** to i***i***?

Also, in case anyone was wondering what I originally thought the solution was...

```
picked_words[(picked_words.find(guess))]
```

I thought that it would simplify and become picked_words[index]

Comment: By the way, according to PEP8, use `if correct` instead of `if correct == True`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of converting your code to the hangman game.

Note how variable display in the code is updated to show user the correct guessed letters.

```
import random

def hangman():
    words = ['utopia', 'prosecute', 'delirious', 'superficial', 'fowl', 'abhorrent', 'divergent', 
'noxious', 'scarce','lavish', 'hinder', 'onerous', 'colossal', 'infringe']

    max_guesses = 5
    word = random.choice(words)
    guesses = 0
    display = "*" * len(word)
    print(display, " Is the word")
    while guesses < max_guesses:
        letter = input("Please Enter Your guess letter: ")
        if letter.lower() not in word:
            guesses += 1
            print("You got it incorrect, you have: ", max_guesses - guesses , " Additional    trials")
        else:
            print("Right guess!")
            new_display = ''
            for w, l in zip(word, display):
                if letter.lower() == w:
                    new_display += letter.lower()
                else:
                    new_display += l
            display = new_display
            print(display)
            if not '*' in display:
                print("You won!")
                return

hangman()
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will need to find a partial match between your letter and the word here.
The easiest way i can think of is Pythons `in` Operator. It can be used like this

```
if picked_letter in picked words

% here you need to figure out at which position(s) the letter in your word occurs 
% and then replace the * at the correct positions. A nice way to do this is 
% the use of regular expressions 

picked_words = re.sub('[^[^picked_letter]*$]', '*', picked_words)

%this will replace every letter in your word with the Asterisk except for the one picked


else

%do Nothing
```

Note that running this Code in a loop would replace every character in your string except the picked one EVERY time., therefore it is probably best to design your picked_letter as a list containing all characters that have been picked so far. This also makes it easier to check wether a letter has already been entered.